# How to connect EC2 instance(ubuntu,VPC) to my local linux machine

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an EC2 instance on AWS. From the AWS server, I am attempting to POST data and then receive that data from my local Linux machine using HTTP POST and GET methods. However, both code snippets are getting stuck at the line where the response is expected.

aws server side code

```
``import requests
import pymongo
import time

# MongoDB connection
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://your_mongodb_connection_string")
db = client["MYdatabase"]
collection = db["MYcollection"]

# Continuously send data to AWS server
while True:
    # Sample data to send
    data = {"abc": 123 }
    print(data)
    # Send data to AWS server
    response = requests.post("https://3.110.118.49", json=data)
    print(response)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("Data sent successfully to AWS server")
    else:
        print("Failed to send data to AWS server")

    # Wait for 10 seconds before sending the next data
    time.sleep(5)``
`
```

linux local machine side code

```
type here``import requests
import tkinter as tk

# Function to receive data from AWS server
def receive_data():
    print("receive data function")
    # Receive data from AWS server
    response = requests.get("https://3.110.118.49")
    print(response)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        # Do something with the received data
        print("Data received from AWS server:", data)
        # Update the Tkinter label with the received data
        label.config(text="Data received: " + str(data))
    else:
        print("Failed to receive data from AWS server")

# Tkinter GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("AWS Data Receiver")

# Label to display received data
label = tk.Label(root, text="")
label.pack()

# Button to receive data
receive_button = tk.Button(root, text="Receive Data", command=receive_data)
receive_button.pack()

# Start Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()`
```

`

I am attempting to send data from my AWS EC2 instance to my local machine and then receive that data locally. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood how HTTP requests work. It seems like you think `GET` and `POST` requests connect to each other. But that is not the case. HTTP requests work where one side is the `Client` and the other side is the `Server`. The `Client` sends an HTTP request - such as `GET` and `POST` requests. Whereas the `Server` takes this requests and sends the appropriate data back.

Here is an article where you can learn more about `Clients` and `Servers` and how they talk to each other: [what-is-a-client-server-architecture](https://educative.io/courses/learn-rest-soap-api-test-automation-java/what-is-a-client-server-architecture)

To recap, you'll need to make one of the computers a `Server`. Right now they are both acting as `Clients`. You can use a library like `flask` to accomplish
it. Here is an example of `Server` code using `flask`.

```
# Importing flask module in the project is mandatory
# An object of Flask class is our WSGI application.
from flask import Flask
 
# Flask constructor takes the name of 
# current module (__name__) as argument.
app = Flask(__name__)
 
# The route() function of the Flask class is a decorator, 
# which tells the application which URL should call 
# the associated function.
@app.route('/')
# ‘/’ URL is bound with hello_world() function.
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'
 
# main driver function
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # run() method of Flask class runs the application 
    # on the local development server.
    app.run()
```